# TinyMCE not injected with Bower

Tags: gruntjs, tinymce, bower

When starting my application with Grunt I get the error that "TinyMCE was not injected in your file". It also tells me to manually add the file. My only problem is that I have no idea what file to include?

My error looks like this:

```
MichaelTot@LENOVO-PC ~/Desktop/Code Projects/Web/Academia/Academia Unitate - Js
$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (19 files)
>> Nothing changed

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (9 files)
>> Nothing changed

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task

tinymce was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "c:\Users\MichaelTot\Desktop\Code Projects\Web\Academia\Academia Unitate -
Js\client\bower_components\tinymce" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Debugger listening on port 5858
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[undefined:undefined] CONNECTED
```